# Bluff while Invisible

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, invisibility

My character is invisible.

Does using bluff to deceive or pass secret messages render my character visible?

Do they count as an attack? I don't believe they count as a spell.

The wording on Invisibility says that targets may speak freely.

Do those uses of bluff break the spell?

Answer (score 2):

No bluffing doesn't break invisibility, but your DM might place a disadvantage based solely on the fact of the suspicion of an invisible person trying to claim something.

Comment: Well, they saw him disappear so they know that he is a real person.

Comment: same end result